# DOM Parser in Java, attributes and tag values

Tags: java, parsing, dom

```
            <SimpleData name="RATE">$1.00</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="LIMIT">2hr</SimpleData>
```

On that piece of XML how do I access each individual tag value? So far I have this:

```
if(eElement.getAttribute("name").equals("RATE"))
  System.out.println("Rate : " + getTagValue("SimpleData", eElement));
```

Which checks for the attribute "name" and compares it, but I'm having trouble getting the LIMIT value. I think my problem is in my getTagValue method:

```
  private static String getTagValue(String sTag, Element eElement) {
    NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0).getChildNodes();

        Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);

    return nValue.getNodeValue();
  }
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You've got

```
if(eElement.getAttribute("name").equals("RATE")) {
   System.out.println("Rate : " + getTagValue("SimpleData", eElement));
}
```

What's wrong with:

```
else if(eElement.getAttribute("name").equals("LIMIT")) {
   System.out.println("Limit : " + getTagValue("SimpleData", eElement));
}
```